# How to access the current [web] page (outside of the current page)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

The situation is this:

I have an abstract class used globally that used to reference a Session variable via a public property.  We now want to change its behavior to return a property on a master page.

(By simply changing the guts of this particular property, we hope to avoid doing a lot of rewrites)

This is just a snippet of the class:

```
   public abstract class AppSession
   {
        public static CaseNumber CurrentCaseNo
        {
            /* OLD METHOD DELETED */

            get
            {
                if (CurrentPage.Master != null)
                 // property on the master page
                  return CurrentPage.Master.CurrentCaseNo;
                else
                  throw new Exception("This page has no master page");
            }
        }
    }
```

Above, "CurrentPage" is not real/valid.  I just wrote that there to show context.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!
J

Comment: It sounds like you're not doing something correct here, what exactly are you trying to retrieve from the master page?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `HttpContext.Current` object.  I believe it's `Handler` property will return the currently executing page.  It would be easier to read a value stored in the Session that pulling it out of a property since the Session is available off of `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556058/how-to-access-the-current-web-page-outside-of-the-current-page/1556106#1556106), this can be used statically throughout your application:

```
Page myPage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

if( myPage != null )
    return ((MyMaster)myPage.Master).CurrentCaseNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would need to work with something that took a "page" object in as a parameter, and from there, you could determine if the page that was passed is your master page.  And do what you need from there....

But that adds quite a bit of overhead.

The real question here is what are you trying to avoid?  Trying to get rid of session and move to viewstate?

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to pass in the Page as a parameter.  We had considered that and it's our last choice.  Yes, we are trying to get away from the session variable.  Thanks.